# Java - Saving 2 consecutive lines in blocks and output in opposite order

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, reverse

I am trying to store every 2 consecutive lines of inputs into a "block" and output the "block" of lines in reverse order, but in the order in which they were read.

input:

```
cat

dog

bunny

fish
```

output:

```
bunny

fish

cat

dog
```

I have tried using an `ArrayList` to store the lines

Comment: Welcome to SO, perhaps if you tell us what part of the problem you are struggling with, and what you have tried to solve it we might be better able to help :). At a first pass i would suggest you need to figure out what steps you need to take, try working it out on paper first?

Answer (score 0):

There could be several approaches to resolving this task:

1. A list of lists/arrays should be used to store a pair of the input lines:

```java
public static void reverseBlock(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    List<String> pair = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        pair.add(line);
        if (pair.size() == 2) {
            list.add(pair);
            pair = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    if (!pair.isEmpty()) { // check for an odd number of lines in the input
        list.add(pair);
    }
    Collections.reverse(list);
    for (List<String> p : list) {
        for (String text : p) {
            w.println(text);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Use method `List::add(int index, E element)` to insert lines in appropriate order.

The approach above is overly excessive and a simpler way should be used.

If we look at the order of insertion of the initial data, we can see that the elements should be inserted in this way:

```java
list.add(0, "cat");   // ["cat"]
list.add(1, "dog");   // ["cat", "dog"]
list.add(0, "bunny"); // ["bunny", "cat", "dog"]
list.add(1, "fish");  // ["bunny", "fish", "cat", "dog"]
...
```

So the entire method could be rewritten as:

```java
public static void reverseBlock(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(list.size() % 2, line);
    }

    for (String text : list) {
        w.println(text);
    }
}
```

Here `list.size() % 2` provides a sequence of `0, 1, 0, 1` without extra counter / loop.  Also, `LinkedList` should be used here because it should have better performance when inserting elements at the head of the list.